# All USB ports disabled at Ubuntu 22 boot

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard

I use Ubuntu 22 (which worked some days before).

After boot, all my USB ports are disabled. I can't do anything with my keyboard except on GRUB menu or GRUB shell... And even when booting on a bootable key with Ubuntu Live, it finish with USB ports disabled and I can't continue...

Trying to load an other version of Ubuntu from "Advanced Ubuntu Options" finish with the same bad  result.

I'm sure my keyboard, mouse, and USB ports are functionnals.

Here are the specifications of my PC :

HP EliteDesk 800 G3 DM 35W
i5 6500T CPU @ 2.50Hz
System BIOS P21 Ver. 02.31 10/15/2019

Please help ! :)

Comment: did you disable them in BIOS or something like that? Does it work in the live USB? What is the last thing you changed?

Comment: UEFI update may revert settings to defaults. If UEFI Secure Boot on, it may have USB setting to turn them all off. As allowing boot via USB is not "secure". Check UEFI settings.

Comment: Ubuntu 22?  So you're using Ubuntu Core 22 & the *specialist* server product & not the main Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server (or Desktop) on which the 22 *flavor* is based.